# Pie charts in google map using plotGoogleMaps

Tags: r, google-maps, coordinates, pie-chart

I am trying to add some pie charts in a list of coordinates. Please find attached the data I am using: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/834f4ztfnv1o394/g9NbU8WeFt

Basically I am using this code:

```
data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)  
coordinates(data) = ~ x + y  
proj4string(data) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 
mychart<-segmentGoogleMaps(data, zcol=c('City','Village'),mapTypeId='ROADMAP',  
   filename='myMap4.htm',colPalette=c('#E41A1C','#377EB8'), strokeColor='black')
```

But a map with legends shows up without any points or pie charts.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `segmentGoogleMaps` function in the R package `plotGoogleMaps`, see the example in the help of the function:

```
 # Data preparation
 data(meuse)
 coordinates(meuse)<-~x+y
 proj4string(meuse) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992')

 m<-segmentGoogleMaps(meuse,zcol=c('zinc','lead','copper'))
```

and the result : 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the solution below you will get small barplots in the map (for some reason pie-charts didn't work; moreover pie-charts are no a very good way of visualizing data in my opinion).

```
# loading the required packages
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggmap)
require(ggsubplot)

# preparing the data
df <- read.csv("sample.csv")
df$id <- sprintf("%02.0f", seq(1,36))
df <- df[,c(5,1,2,3,4)]
colnames(df) <- c("id","lat","lon","City","Village")
dfl <- melt(df, id=c("id","lat","lon"))

# getting the center point of the maps
mean(df$lat) # = 20.03142
mean(df$lon) # = 41.12421

# creating the map with the barplots
albahah <- get_map(location = c(lon = 41.12421, lat = 20.03142), zoom = 8, maptype = "roadmap", scale = 2)

ggmap(albahah) +
  geom_subplot(data = dfl, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = id,
                               subplot = geom_bar(aes(x = variable, y = log10(value),
                                                      fill = variable), stat = "identity")))
```

the result:
[image]

I used a log-scale for the y-axis of the barplots, because else the barplots of the small values would be nearly invisible.

I hope this helps!